# How to show file tabs in sublime text 2

Tags: tabs, sublimetext2

I installed sublime text 2 a while back but didn't buy it at the time. I've now bought it (and loving it!) but it seems that when I first checked it out I disabled the file tabs somehow i.e. the tabs don't show at the top of the screen. Is there a setting somewhere that I can change so that the file tabs show up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Sublime Text 2, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to access quickly to some functionalities.

Type `tabs` and you will find the `View: Toggle Tabs` functionality.

Comment: I am facing rather similar problem. All of the files are opening in the same window, and when I try to do `View:Show Tabs`, it has no effect. `view> Show tabs` also has no effects. Also, I tried `double click`, it also has no effects.